# user = matches[1] object has no attribute '_getitem_' Python errorr

Tags: python, regex, parsing

My python script when runs gets the error

`['dc:9f:db:1a:60:62']`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search.py", line 26, in <module>
    user = matches[1]
TypeError: 'callable-iterator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

**My Script is as follows**

`import re`

`austins_mac_address = "f8:27:93:88:1c:95"`

`dd = {'f8:27:93:88:1c:95' : 'Austin iPhone',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:60:64' : '4-Ops-AP',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:60:62' : '4-TechOffices-AP',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:61:b9' : '7-SalesReception-AP',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:60:63' : '7-Marketing-AP',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:61:bd' : '7-Sales-Engineers-AP',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:60:f3' : '4-Dev-AP',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:2c:dd' : '4-Hurricane-AP',
      '24:a4:3c:02:cf:f6' : '6-Meeting-AP',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:60:ef' : '4-Lounge-AP',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:61:ba' : '7-QA-AP',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:60:5f' : '4-TechFloor-AP',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:2d:95' : '4-training1-AP'}`

`dat = '[2014-07-22 10:21:06,821] <inform_stat-3> WARN  event  - [event] User[e4:98:d6:27:4c:b6] roams from AP[dc:9f:db:1a:60:64] to AP[dc:9f:db:1a:2d:95] on "channel 11(ng)"'
aps = []
import re
for line in open("server.log"):
        matches = re.finditer('(([0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-f]{2})', line)
        if matches:
                macAddrs = []
                for match in matches:
                        macAddrs.append(match.group(0))
                print(macAddrs)
                user = matches[1]
                if (user.equals(austins_mac_address)):
                        source = matches[3]
                        dest = matches[5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `matches` is an iterator, since that's what `re.finditer` returns. Iterators generate their data on the fly; it's not all contained in a data structure at once. That's why you can't just access the second element of it right off the bat. Iterators are designed to be looped though exactly once (like you do at `for match in matches`), not to have random elements accessed at any time.

If you want to be able to access random elements like `matches[1]`, you need to first loop through the iterator and store all of its data in another list.

```
raw_matches = re.finditer('(([0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-f]{2})', line)
if raw_matches:
        matches = []
        for match in raw_matches:
                matches.append(match)
```

Something like that, assuming the first object is not destroyed when the second is generated.